# Probability of getting 2 Consecutive heads in N throws.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms, programming

We have to Find a Probability of Getting ${2}$ consecutive Heads in ${N}$ throws Given that $N^{th}$ throw will always be Head.

For Example:- N = 3,
Possible Conditions = HHH, HTH, THH, TTH = 4 possible conditions where Head will always comes last.

Favourable conditions = 1st and 3rd because in these conditions, 2 Heads comes consecutively. So answer will be $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$

For N = 2, Possible conditions = HH, TH = 2
Favourable conditions = HH = 1 => Probability = $\frac{1}{2}$.

I have to print answer in ${P*Q^{-1}\ modulo\ 10^{9}+7}$

So, actual answer for ${N = 3}$ is ${500000004}$ and for N = 2 is also ${500000004}$

What i have found is total number of possibel conditions is ${2^{N-1}}$ but i am not able to figure out number of favourable conditions. Please tell how to solve this questions.

Comment: Getting *at least* $2$ consecutive heads ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes..atleast 2 consecutinve Heads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use complementary counting here.

We know there are $2^{N-1}$ outcomes for the first $N-1$ tosses. In order to not have any consecutive heads, the $N-1$th toss must be $T$. Then we have $N-1$ tosses where our options are $T$ or $HT$ since each head must be followed immediately by a tail.

We think of $T$ is a monomino and $HT$ as a domino and are tiling $N-1$ squares with some combination of monominos and dominos. Notice we are ensuring the $N-1$th toss will be a tails.

Suppose there are $\mathcal{S}_{N-1}$ ways to tile. If the $N-1$th square is covered by a monomino. Then there are $\mathcal{S}_{N-2}$ options for the initial $N-2$ tosses. If $N-1$th and subsequently $N-2$th squares are covered by a domino then there are $\mathcal{S}_{N-3}$ ways to tile. Hence $$S_{N-1} = S_{N-2} + S_{N-3}.$$ Notice this is the recurrence relation for the Fibonacci numbers. Where $1 = F_1 = \mathcal{S}_0$ since there is $1$ way to tile no squares. And $1 = F_2 = \mathcal{S}_1$ since there is $1$ way to tile $1$ square (i.e. with a monomino). Thus, $F_N = \mathcal{S}_{N-1}$. Thus we have $F_N$ outcomes with no consecutive heads.

So the probability of consecutive heads when the $N$th toss is guaranteed heads is $$1 - \frac{F_N}{2^{N-1}} = \frac{2^{N-1}-F_N}{2^{N-1}}.$$

**Example:** Let $N = 4$. There are a total of $2^{N-1} = 2^3 = 8$ outcomes that end with $H$. They are $$HHHH, HHTH, HTHH, THHH, TTHH, THTH, HTTH, TTTH.$$ Of these $8$ outcomes, the ones with no consecutive heads are $$HTTH, THTH, TTTH.$$ There are $F_4 = 3$ of these so the probability of getting consecutive heads is $$\frac{8 - 3}{8} = \frac{5}{8}$$ as expected (since we wrote out the $5$ options that do).

Notice that the $3$ "bad" outcomes have $HT$ (dominos) and $T$ monominos tiling the first $N-1$ spots.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain with example? for N = 4, can you please explain?

Comment: Certainly! Check the edit

Comment: @netqst let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: How you get F4 as 3 ? Is there any formula that i can use? rather than writing all possible cases?

Comment: It is the fourth fibonacci number. $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1, F_3 = 2, F_4 = 3$ (by summing the previous two). And it counts the number of outcomes with no consecutive heads.

Comment: Oh..Okay..I have to get Nth Fibnocci Number? right?

Comment: Yes but you can do this without going through the recurrence since there is a closed form expression. $F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$ where $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = 1 - \varphi = -\frac{1}{\varphi}$.

Comment: Yeah..actually N can be very large i.e.10^5. So i have to calculate Fibnocci and 2^(N-1) with Modulo arithmetic

Comment: If you have to do that I would suggest Euler's theorem to reduce the size quickly: $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ where $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Since $10^9 + 7$ is prime then $\phi(10^9 + 7) = 10^9 + 6$ so this should definitely help reduce the size effectively.